# How to assign list elements as an index of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list named `dof[]` which contains global dof's
`E1` is a `2D` array of order 8x8
`E` is a `2D` array of order 18x18.
I want to assemble E1 inside E using index numbers defined in `dof[]` list.
How can I do that?

```
dof = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17]

E1 = [[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 8 4 4 4]
 [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]]
```

and

```
E = [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

E1 should get assembled according to the index defined in `dof[]` list. it's not a sequential assembly.

Comment: What are the expected values of `E1` and `E` from `dof` that is given in the question?

Comment: Thanks for writing. E is a global matrix (18x18 order), right now initialized with zeros. E1 is a local matrix (8X8 order) having values as written in question. dof [] is having a a list as displayed. dof [] list should become index of global matrix E. Is it possible to do this?